# Checking whether a relation is an equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, relations, equivalence-relations

I am a bit confused whether the following relation is an equivalence relation or not.
$\sim$ is defined on the set of all integers $x \sim y$ if and only if $x = \pm 
 y$. I thought this is an equivalence relation since I checked it for reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity and according to my scratch work, all of them are satisfied. Am I missing something or am I on the right track?

Comment: Did you mean to write $x=\pm y$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos   yeah x = (plus/minus) y

Comment: Given that you meant $x=\pm y$ then, yes.  This is an equivalence relation.

Comment: Yes, you got it right.

Comment: You can also prove this using the fundamental theorem of equivalence relations since sets of the form $\{x,-x\}$ partition the integers.

Comment: Yes, confidence.